# separate chaining vs linear probing

Tags: chaining

a set of objects with keys: 12, 44, 13, 88, 23, 94, 11, 39, 20, 16, 5
 Write the hash table where M=N=11 and collisions are handled using separate chaining.

h(x) = | 2x + 5 | mod M

So I did it with linear probing and got

11 39 20 5 16 44 88 12 23 13 94

which I am pretty sure is right, but how do you do it with separate chaining? I realize separate chaining uses linked lists, but how would the hash table look like?